# Adding Paragraph element on iText pdf goes to next page

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

Below is the code used to create a paragraph. `dpa.getName()` will get the HTML content from another piece of code which consists of HTML tags which are then removed and passed on to the cell.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] {100});
table.setWidthPercentage(100);

//This code takes the HTML and converts it to a list of iText objects
//which can then be rendered on PDF
StringReader stream = new StringReader(Utilities.parseForHTMLWorker(dpa.getName()));
PdfPCell dpaCell = makeBodyCell("");
try {
        ArrayList list = HTMLWorker.parseToList( stream, null);
        for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {
            Paragraph p = (Paragraph)list.get(i);
            dpaCell.addElement(p);
        }            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.Log("InitialInterviewDetailsPrint", "render()", e.toString(), 1);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
table.addCell(dpaCell);
```

The `list` variable gets a list of `Paragraph`. These paragraphs are big enough with at least 10 sentences. Even if there is space to accommodate 5 lines at the bottom of the page, all contents are moved to the new page. I don't want this blank space left at the bottom of the page and want the paragraph to split its contents in both the pages.

Is there any specific property that needs to be set on the Paragraph to have them on the same page?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `setKeepTogether` method to force `iText`

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("");
paragraph.setKeepTogether(false);
```

or

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(numberOfColumns);
table.setKeepTogether(false);
```

As you can see in [API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html):

```
protected boolean keeptogether
//Does the paragraph has to be kept together on 1 page.
```

Comment: The content is as such already together. I want it to actually break. May be i need to be more clear in saying there is more content above this piece of code and this piece of code adds the content in the next page, since it doesn't have enough space to fit in. It doesn't want to break itself and spread the content in two pages. I will make some changes in the above question to make it more clear.

Comment: If you want to break them simply divide into various cells and manage it sepparately...

Comment: Its random content and comes from the parser. So its not under my control to break them

Comment: I dont't get what you want to do...  ;) Can you edit your question and explain your input and your needs with more detail??